# Explain expansion of the scope macro

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The Phoenix.Router manual page [states](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/3):

```
scope(path, options, list)
```

Define a scope with the given path.

This function is a shortcut for:

```
scope path: path do
  ...
end
```

One of the parameters in this macro invocation is `options`. I thought that the list was the part that starts with `do` and ends with `end`. Can someone kindly explain where `options` is expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `list` here is a one element list that contains `[do: block]` where `block` is the code within `do ... end`. The documentation is not very clear here, but you can [read the source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.1/lib/phoenix/router.ex#L591) to understand this better.

In short, `path` is inserted into `options` if options is a list, so:

```
scope(path, options, list)
```

is equivalent to

```
scope([path: path] ++ options, list)
```

if `options` is a list, and equivalent to

```
scope([path: path, alias: options], list)
```

if `options` is an atom (which is treated as the scope's alias).

The reason the argument is named `list` in the docs is that the function doesn't have a function head declaration on top, which makes ex_doc infer a name, and it chooses to use `list` since the function accepts a list `[do: block]` as the last argument. You can read more about this [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/writing-documentation.html#function-arguments).

Comment: Assuming you refer to the `scope` macro as the function not having a function head declaration, how would such a declaration look like? I could not find it in the source code you pointed to.

Comment: Yes, I mean the `scope` macro. It'll look like `defmacro scope(path, options, foo)` (no `do ... end` body).